# Best way to change color of several items in a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors

I'm afraid I don't have the code available here to paste, but I'd appreciate some guidance on best practices.

I currently have a polygon defined in my XAML file in Visual Studio 2010, C#, .NET 4.0. The polygon is defined with a fixed color; however, depending on the value of the binding, the color can change using a trigger.

```
// non-working code - trying to avoid
<Polygon ... Fill="Red" />
<Grid.Triggers>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Yellow" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Green" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Blue" />
   </Trigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Now, I need to break up the polygon into several pieces that are joined together to look like one complete shape. I have broken up the polygon into two polygons and a rectangle.

What is the best way to change colors as before such that I don't repeat code?

I don't want a trigger mapping four different enum values to four different colors, and then for each color, defining the same three shapes to be colored.

```
// non-working code - trying to avoid
<Polygon ... Fill="Red" />
<Polygon ... Fill="Red" />
<Rectangle ... Fill="Red" />
<Grid.Triggers>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Yellow" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Yellow" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Yellow" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Green" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Green" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Green" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Blue" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Blue" />
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Blue" />
   </Trigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Is there a way I can define a color as a static resource and use that resource to color my three shapes, and then use the trigger to toggle the R/G/B values of the resource?

```
// non-working code - trying to do
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Red"/>
<Polygon ... Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}" />
<Polygon ... Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}" />
<Rectangle ... Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}" />
<Grid.Triggers>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Yellow" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Green" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger ...>
      <Setter Property="..." Value="Blue" />
   </Trigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the property for your triggers?

Comment: In the first two snippets, I would think the property would be brush color for the polygons or rectangles. In the third snippet, I was hoping I could set some property of `MyBrush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is called using Binding with Converter instead of having tons of triggers listening to different states. :)

Here is code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BelowZeroConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="1">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: You are right, it would probably help the op better. I will see what I can do. However I hope the op is capable to google keywords converter and binding. He will let us know if he cant find anything :)

Comment: All of this is inside a `ControlTemplate` used to style something like a `Button`. Would this still work? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, DataTrigger will allow you to set Binding and Converter.

Comment: I think a code sample would help; it doesn't have to compile--just something to give me an idea of what you mean. Thanks.